# ASCII tree, but python does not agree

Tags: python, encoding, ascii

I have this python script, with a tree for documentation purposes:

```
# This is the tree, generated with:
#   $ tree -A a
#     a
#     └── tree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'It runs'
```

If I run it:

```
  File "xxx.py", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file xxx.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I know I can solve that error adding for example:

```
#coding: utf8
```

at the top of my script, but I am curious: why does the `tree` man page say that `-A` outputs ASCII:

```
-A     Turn on ANSI line graphics hack when printing the indentation lines.
```

but `python` does not recognize the tree as `ASCII`? Who is wrong? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: It all depends on your editor, the console, your OS and it's locale. I'm sure someone can correct me on this one or explain it better. But for all intense and purposes, encoding and special characters never have a easy "workaround". In this case `#coding: utf-8` is actually an easy solution.

Comment: I agree with python, the characters  `└──` on line 4 are **not** ASCII.

Comment: The -A actually refers specifically to "line graphic hack" and not real ANSI. In old machines, upper ASCII was used used by special characters (such as ```└```) in computers that supported only one language. This was used to draw frames and other basic graphics on the screen. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting! I would accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not ASCII.  ANSI line grpahics is not the same as ASCII; and ASCII has no line drawing characters.  ASCII defines only bytes 0x00 - 0x7F.

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html
- http://worldpowersystems.com/J/codes/X3.4-1963/

Comment: Right, I was confused then (I though ANSI == ASCII)